# How to modify same document, instead it creates another one firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i need to be able to create a doc, and at the same nano second update it.

here is my code

```
await room.get().then((QuerySnapshot Snapshots) async {
    // loop all collections
    for (var Element in Snapshots.docs) {
      int index = Element['users'].length;

      if (Element['users'][index - 1]['email'] != email &&
          index < maxUsers!) {
        //print(index);
        List defaultList = [];
        var map = {
          '''data'''
        };
        existedRoomId = Element.id;
        defaultList.add(map);
        userNotAddedToRoom = false;

        return await fi.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot = Element;
          transaction.get(snapshot.reference);
          transaction.update(snapshot.reference,
              {'users': FieldValue.arrayUnion(defaultList)});
          return null;
        }).then((value) {
          print("current user added to room");
        }).catchError((error) => print("Failed to add to room: $error"));
      }
    }
    if (userNotAddedToRoom) {
      // create a room

      return await room
          .doc(roomId)
          .set({
            ''data'''
          })
          .then((value) => print("Room Added"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add room: $error"));
    }
  });
```

also check dateCreated in both images
[image]
[image]

its not suppose to create a room if there is one with an spot available

Comment: Hi, Have you managed to check the below comment

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentations of [**flutterFire**](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#adding-documents) if the passed documentId(roomId) already exists in the collection then it will overwrite the existing data in the document when `.set()` method is used. But when the passed documentId(roomId) does not exist in the collection it will create a new document with the documentId we just passed.

So in your case the roomId you are passing will most likely to be not exist in the `rooms` collection you can check this by

```
print(roomId)
```

Before you are updating, make sure you are using the update method here as the `.set()`  method will overWrite the existing data. Your update query will look something like this

```
print(roomId); // check this must be a new documentId 
return await room
          .doc(roomId)
          .update({
            ''data''',
          })
```

The query will change the value of that field in the Firestore document if the data object contains any existing field names with the new value.

Reference : [**Updating documents**](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents)

Comment: The code works if the users not execute the function at the same time, but i need something to identify wich one was the first but in milliseconds, i don’t know if made myself understand

Comment: To handle concurrent writes check this document on [Updating data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)